# rails how to decide controller according to the url dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

let's say I have two controllers `apple` and `banana`, and I want to assign them according to the url dynamically. for example, I want to do something like

```
match 'eat/:fruit' => ':fruit#eat'
```

in my `routes.rb`. I expect that when I access the url `eat/apple`, rails would use `apple#eat`. otherwise, rails would use `banana#eat` for `eat/banana`.

is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters

I think this will work:

```
match ':action/:controller'
```